# Youtrack: Workflow - Shedule rule

Tags: email, workflow, youtrack

I wrote a rule to send an Email with a list of issues which were set to closed in the last week.
The Problem is, I always get a lot of emails with the same kontent. (I get one email for each Issue)

Here ist the code i wrote in youtrack-workflow editor:

```
schedule rule:
weekly on Monday at 12:08:00 [project == {projekt1}] 
{
   var ClosedIssuesList = "";
   for each Issue in project.issues 
   {
        var Date = Issue.updated;
        if (Issue.State == {Closed} && now < Date + 7 days) 
        {
           ClosedIssuesList = ClosedIssuesList + Issue.getId() + "\n";
        }
   }
   project.getUser("username").notify("Closed Issues", ClosedIssuesList);
}
```

How can I fix this problem?
Thanks for Your help!

Comment: Did you base your rule on this? http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/YTD5/Workflow+Language+Quick+Reference#WorkflowLanguageQuickReference-ProjectbasedReports

Answer (score 0):

The workflow runs once for each issue that satisfies the criteria.  In your case, the criteria is `[project == {projekt1}]`, which satisfies every issue in the project.

You need to write something like the example that @artem-goutsoul referred to in the comment above.  From that example:

`weekly on Monday at 12:00:00 [issue == {issue: A-1}] { 
   ...`

Replace `A-1` with some random issue ID in the project.  This issue won't actually be used in the rule, but it will restrict the criteria to a single item.  (I supposed that's a bit of a hack, but such is life!)